# Intentionally slow decryption

Tags: decryption, performance

We need to store the user ID of authors of messages in a database.

It should be *possible to find an author of a problematic message* i.e. on police request in minutes, but *it should be very hard to find all the messages of an author* (because we have no legal obligation (yet) to do this and we want to save our users privacy). So we need an encryption which allows us to decrypt but needs a lot of time to do so.

Therefore I was considering to encrypt the associated user ID of the message with the message as key - so that an attacker may need a lot of CPU time to decrypt the user IDs of many many millions of messages to create an index.
This would be even harder if we could implement a **really time consuming decryption method**. Is there such?

**Background:**
The Austrian government will introduce a law which will make all providers of public forums, news site's comments, chats, social media, etc. obliged to have all their user registered by *validating their real ID* with a document like a passport. The police and intelligence agencies will be allowed to access this (to find the author of a message) - "to fight online harassment". 
This makes us fear, that once all this data is collected, the police and intelligence agencies will demand access the whole data - but the other way around. Not to fight harassment by one message but to get all contributions a user did in the last years on all media platforms all together. To get an *exact political profile* of everyone (history teaches us this is always one of the first steps in applied fascism).

Comment: There's no end to slow algorithms. But why don't you just put a [speed-up loop](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Speedup-Loop) (or better yet, Thread.sleep) into the relevant endpoints?

Comment: Why not just use a very slow or complex encryption algorithm ? That will automatically be slow by default and have nothing suspect about it.

Comment: You can use a KDF (key derivation function) such as scrypt or argon2, using a hash of the message as the initial key. Then use the derived key to encrypt the username, with the symmetric encryption algorithm of your choice. Be careful to choose a KDF accepting binary inputs and not just passwords.

Comment: One thing you should consider is, the attacker is going to be able to dedicate a lot more resources at brute-force decryption if they can perform an offline decryption attack.  Think things like throwing a GPU cluster at the problem, which you can just rent on Amazon, for instance.  A few minutes of CPU time on your rig might turn into a few milliseconds on the attackers.  So for the time to decrypt to be relevant, you have to make your resources similar to an attackers.  If you're not worried about offline decryption, the use the sleep/wait as John suggested.

Comment: My target is to make decryption as time consuming as possible. The most obvious would be to run multiple rounds of the same encryption with the same key in a loop. Let's say 256 times output is the input for the next round. Or, use KDF to generate a stretched key which is so long that I can provide each round in the loop with a unique new key? Where are the flaws?

Comment: @user2661619 Why not _only_ use a KDF? Decryption can be fast as long as it takes a long time to _begin_ decryption.

Comment: @forest You are totally right! I forgot that one of the initial targets of key derivation functions was to slow down the key generation. Face-palm. Thanks! If you want to publish this as answer I would mark it as accepted

Comment: @user2661619 I already did, at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/209492/165253. :P

Comment: @JohnDvorak If downvoting comments was a feature here, I'd do so for your's to reflect the counter-productiveness of the suggestion. When you're legally compelled to cooperate then you will also be compelled to remove the "speed up loop" or sleep. Or the police can copy the database and do the decryption on their own computer. Now you're wasting your own CPU time while enabling police to process the database with no delays.

Comment: @FutureSecurity your comment would have been just as useful without the first sentence. Just saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is a slow KDF which processes a stored or memorized password and converts it into a key for decryption. The actual decryption process can proceed rapidly, as long as the key-derivation takes a long time. There are a number of algorithms that can do this, such as PBKDF2, Argon2, and scrypt. If each stored record contains its own password that must be first put through a strong KDF before the record can be decrypted, then you will be able to enforce a configurable delay to access.

I strongly suggest, however, that you contact a lawyer rather than trying to implement a technical solution yourself. There may be better legal alternatives that would allow you to get away with not storing *any* data. Never assume that your own interpretation of the law is the only possible interpretation.

Comment: About the lawyer, see the background of the question I added above. The positive side of Austria is that we have no Common Law but instead Statutory Law.
What's written in Austrian law is what it is. No precedent of a senile judge about horses in Nebraska 1874 to be applied on computers ... If you can read code from your boss you can also understand Austrian Law. ;) That's one reasons why lawyers in Germany or Austria earn so much less than lawyers in the States btw. 
But thanks for your answer!

Comment: I need the *slow key-derivation* process to take place on the browser and for the user to then submit the results to the server and then the server will decrypt the data. Is this possible ?

Comment: @SproutCoder Sure. You can run a KDF in the browser, but you'll need to be careful that your implementation is both side-channel resistant and not overly inefficient.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Actually, bad idea (see comments). Don't listen to people who aren't crypto people about cryptography, especially me!

When you want crypto where it's quick to do things one way but slow to do them another, you probably want [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) in some way.

How about this:

For each user, store a list of hashed message IDs. Then if you want to know who sent a particular message you can hash the message ID (quick) and then search through the list of message ID / user ID pairs to find out who it belongs to (also pretty quick for sensible numbers of messages, certainly fine if it's not something you do often). If someone wanted to find all the messages a particular person had sent on the other hand, they'd have to retrieve all the hashed massage IDs connected to their user ID and then break each hash individually, which for a decent cryptographic hashing algorithm will take a very long time indeed.

Comment: When you have a list of all potential hash candidates, "breaking" a hash only takes at most as long as hashing each candidate, which is probably not a very long time.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald damn, good point.